# How do I inject EntityManager into a EJB using Bluemix Liberty runtime?

Tags: java, jpa, ibm-cloud

It was supposed to be a trivial thing to do and it's described [here](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/04/07/ejbs-bluemix-jpa-db2/) (which injects `EntityManagerFactory` and not `EntityManager`), [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-bluemix-fundamentals-intro-to-sql-database-services-for-java-apps/) (which does not inject `EntityManager`, but retrieves it from `Persistence` object) and [here](http://blog.advteknology.com/jee-rest-bluemix-api-2/) (which actually injects `EntityManager` in the way I want, and what it says makes sense, since it assumes the data source is called `jdbc/<yourdbname>`)

However, the third one has a broken link because the source code is not available any more, unfortunately.

My persistence.xml uses JPA 2.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="mycogdb">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/cogdb</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and my EJB could not be any simpler

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
public class MyEJB {

     @PersistenceContext(unitName="mycogdb")
     private EntityManager em;

    public void test() {
        MyEntity me = new MyEntity();
        me.setId(System.currentTimeMillis());
        em.persist(me);
    }
}
```

However, it's not being injected

```
    [ERROR ] CWWJP0029E: The server cannot find the <default> persistence 
unit in the myapp.war module and the myapp application.
    2016-06-17T08:39:02.541-0300
    [App/0]
    out
    [INFO ] FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: 
"com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException: 
The java:comp/env/mycogdb reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager 
for the null component in the myapp.war module of the myapp application 
cannot be resolved. com.ibm.ejs.container.ManagedBeanOBase.injectInstance 
134" at ffdc_16.06.17_11.39.02.0.log
```

Am I missing any configuration in server.xml or in any other config file? Maybe any missing server feature to be enabled? Any help is welcome.

Comment: What features do you have configured in your server.xml?

Comment: <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
  <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
  <feature>jsf-2.2</feature>
  <feature>managedBeans-1.0</feature>
  <feature>jpa-2.1</feature>
  <feature>ejbLite-3.2</feature>

Comment: Where is persistence.xml packaged within your WAR/EAR?   ( I deleted my earlier answer since it turned out not to be relevant. )

Comment: haha bingo! persistence.xml was at src/main/java/META-INF while the right place was src/main/resources/META-INF - inspecting the WAR file built by DevOps, the persistence.xml file wasn't there! (because eclipse added it when I've added the JPA facet, but since it's a maven project, it generated the file in the wrong place!) -- pls add your answer so I can vote on it here. Thanks @scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edited:  Originally noted that the annotation attribute is **unitName** not **name** but that ended up not being the problem.]

However the build is performed, make sure the end result is that the persistence.xml ends up in location **WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml** within the WAR archive.

This is mentioned in [JPA Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/819-3669/bnbrj/index.html):

> If you package the persistence unit as a set of classes in a WAR file,
>   persistence.xml should be located in the WAR file’s
>   WEB-INF/classes/META-INF directory.

Now, that still might leave some questions regarding how to structure the project from both the Eclipse/WDT and Maven angles, as well as integration of your Maven build with the DevOps tool which has [Maven integration](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-use-maven-with-the-bluemix-delivery-pipeline/).

I won't attempt to give a complete answer here across all options, but just noting that it might be more complicated than saying "always put your persistence.xml in **src/main/resources**" since **src/main/java/META-INF** appears to me to work in some build use cases.

Comment: if this is the reason I will beat myself 10 times with a hammer in the head

Comment: it seems this was not the case (however, you're right, the right attribute is unitName, but the error persists)